# ext4 for data partition in Windows

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, ext4

I have moved my Windows user profile to a separate partition in order to share it with my linux install. I have originally tried to make a `NTFS` formatted data partition, but this creates some issues on linux (the worst one being apparently that I have no sound after logging in).

My next approach would be to format the data partition with `ext4` and use [ext2fsd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/) to "mount" it in Windows. ext2fsd seems to be reasonably fast for storing my user profile, although it does not support Windows acls.

Is this going to work?

(I'm using Windows 8.1 64-bit with ext2fsd 0.62 and Ubuntu 15.10)

Comment: Instead of sharing your whole profile (most of which is unusable on Linux), you should specifically share portions of it using symlinks/junctions.

Comment: You can share Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Videos folders but don't share other!

Answer (score 0):

I have an ext3 partition that I use as a data partition in both linux and windows via ext2fsd. I've been doing this for 5+ years and it works well. Typically in linux I symlink between home directory folders/profile and corresponding folders on that data partition. Doing a complete symlink of the home directory is not advisable in case you want to boot without the data directory attached.

Going the other direction and mounting ntfs from linux is pretty easy, especially if you are doing read-only. The best way is to update your fstab, but there are a variety of options [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions)

When I do my backups I rsync the data partition, so I don't need to worry about separate backup processes for linux and windows.